# How to get resources path from an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plugin using Eclipse Plugin-in-project where it will add a menu item in the toolbar.

My plugin project is depending on one file which is located in the same plugin project I want the path of that file.

Below is the sample code I have used to get the path:

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("com.feat.eclipse.plugin");
URL fileURL = bundle.getEntry("webspy/lib/file.txt");
File file = null;
String path=null;
try {
    file = new File(FileLocator.resolve(fileURL).toURI());
    path = file.getAbsolutePath();
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

While running from Eclipse *Run as > Eclipse Application* it is giving me the correct path. But when I export my plugin as jar and add it in my Eclipse plugins folder its not giving me the correct path.

Please help me to resolve this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```java
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("webspy/lib/file.txt"), null);

url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);

File file = URIUtil.toFile(URIUtil.toURI(url));
```

When your files are packed in a jar `FileLocator.toFileURL` will copy them to a temporary location so that you can access them using `File`.

Answer (score 0):

Files in jars have no `java.io.File` as they are in the JAR file.

You probably want `FileLocator.openStream(...)` to read the file contents.

If you really want a `java.io.File`, then you can consider using Eclipse EFS and its `IFileStore.toLocalFile(...)` to extract the file for you to a temporary directory. Something like `EFS.getStore(fileURL).toLocalFile(EFS.CACHE, null)` should do what you want, but remember that will put the file in the temp directory and delete it on Eclipse exit.