# How to obtain the resource defined in the plugin.xml

Tags: eclipse-rcp

A bundle , Get the viewpart icon of the org.eclipse.ui.views extension point

Only one string can be obtained through IConfigurationelement
e.g.( icons/full/obj16/julaunch.png )

But I can't get its bundle, and I can't splice a similar URL
e.g.( platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.unittest.ui/icons/full/obj16/julaunch.png )

What should I do?

Comment: This isn't very clear. Probably use `FileLocator` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34924046/2670892)

Comment: In this problem, the bundle is required to obtain the path, and the filelocator also needs the path. However, the path information cannot be obtained without a bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `IContributionElement` and want to get the resource given by an attribute in the element you can do something like:

```java
String pluginId = element.getContributor().getName();

Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(pluginId);

String path = element.getAttribute("attribute id");

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path(path), null);
```

Comment: In fact, I know these APIs, but I don't believe that eclipse provides createExecutableExtension. Why not provide createResource? After all, plugin.xml defines resource

Comment: createExecutableExtension is a much more complicated thing to implement, there is about 90 lines of code in the standard implementation. I imagine the designers didn't think a createResource was needed.

Comment: In "org.eclipse.pde.spy.core.spyprocessor", it is written as "platform.getbundle (e.getnamespaceidentifier());"

Comment: `getNamespaceIdentifier()` gives the same value as getContributor().getName() unless the `<extension` element has an `id` attribute to specify a different name space. In which case it might not be a plug-in id, so I think getContributor().getName() is more correct.